# Module-info.java when there are duplicate dependencies

Tags: java, maven, javafx, java-module, module-info

I have a JavaFX project and I'm using Maven. With the intent of making the software runnable both for Linux and Windows, I have to import each dependecy of JavaFX twice, one for Linux and another for Windows, making the `pom.xml` file looks like this:

```
<!--For Windows-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    <classifier>win</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
    <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    <classifier>win</classifier>
</dependency>
<!--For Linux-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    <classifier>linux</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
    <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    <classifier>linux</classifier>
</dependency>
```

My module-info.java looks like this:

```
requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires javafx.base;
requires javafx.graphics;
requires javafx.media;
requires java.sql;
requires uk.co.caprica.vlcj;
requires uk.co.caprica.vlcj.javafx;

opens org.controllers to javafx.fxml;
exports org.controllers;
```

But my IDE accuses `Ambiguous module reference` for all those javafx imports, besides telling `Module 'ProjectName' reads package 'javafx.beans' from both javafx.base and 'javafx.base'`

The question is: **how can I indicate those duplicated dependencies on the `module-info.java` file?**